# Struts 2 on GAE : Unable to set session values inside interceptor

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, struts2, freemarker

I am writing a Struts 2 interceptor in which I check if the user is valid or not. If not valid, the user is redirected to the Login page. But before that I'm trying to retrieve the URL, which the user has accessed to come here, and put it in a session variable, so that I could redirect him back there when logging in is done. But when I try to put a value inside the session its throwing me the following exception :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class freemarker.template.Configuration
    at org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager.createConfiguration(FreemarkerManager.java:322)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager.init(FreemarkerManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager.getConfiguration(FreemarkerManager.java:260)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:865)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:574)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:368)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:351)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.__handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:485)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Note : It says class not found, but I can see the Configuration class inside the list of libraries in the buildpath.
The piece of code from interceptor :

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println("inside auth interceptor");
    //just to make sure session is created the first time
    HttpSession session = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(true);
    Map<String, Object> sessionAttributes = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

    User user = (User) sessionAttributes.get("user");

    ActionProxy proxy = actionInvocation.getProxy();
    String namespace =  proxy.getNamespace();
    String actionName = proxy.getActionName();

    sessionAttributes.put("returnUrl",  namespace+(actionName == null || actionName.equals("/") ?"":("/"+actionName)));
    //even tried this, but getting same error : 
    //session.setAttribute("returnUrl",  namespace+(actionName == null || actionName.equals("/") ?"":("/"+actionName)));
    System.out.println(namespace+(actionName == null || actionName.equals("/") ?"":("/"+actionName)));

    if(user == null){
        //no user exist. redirect to Login page
        return Action.LOGIN;

    }else
        return actionInvocation.invoke();
}
```

As you see, i even tried `session.setAttribute()` to get the same error. Without putting anything into the session variable, the code runs as expected. So what is that I'm doing wrong?

**Update 1** : I do have the required `freemarker-2.3.19` in `web-inf/lib` and it is added to the build path.

Answer (score 0):

The jar file is required to be on classpath when the project is deployed which should contain the mentioned in the error class. To make sure the file is deployed you can place it in `web-inf/lib` as a temporary measure. You can also assemble a file to the war archive to be deployed at whole. The library file I'm talking about is

```
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
```

If you are using maven then the following dependencies required in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.16</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is the first thing i checked for. I do have this in my `web-inf/lib` folder.