# Sessions on Google App Engine with Java ServletRequestAware not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, struts2

The variables are not stored on a session when the project is Deployed to Google App Engine with Java.
I use the common system that implements ServletRequestAware (works on local and on the current non-google server):

```java
Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        session.put(SESSION_LOGIN, true);
        session.put(SESSION_LOGIN_DATE, new Date());
        session.put(SESSION_LOGIN_ID, idCustomer);
```

I know those variables are not stored because i'm printing them on the logs.

I'm using new **app.yaml** configuration on a Flexible environment.

I've read somewhere that GAE doesn't accept "usual" sessions, instead it uses it's own, but I don't find specific documentation about that.

I'm a bit confused while searching for help, with outdated / not about the same problem / unclear (at least to me) questions and help, like those:

- [Should I use sessions in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349328/should-i-use-sessions-in-google-app-engine)
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref?hl=fr#Java_appengine_web_xml_Enabling_sessions
- [Google app engine sessions now supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675371/google-app-engine-sessions-now-supported)
- [How to deal with Sessions in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689941/how-to-deal-with-sessions-in-google-app-engine)
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/dev/Session

Anybody can point me to the right way to do it? It has to be done with a specific Google library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20761757/573032

Comment: Hi @RomanC, thanks for the redirection. I wasn't using Freemarker, so I don't guess this is the reason. Anyway I've included the reference on the pom.xml because it was somehow on the [struts.properties by default](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/default-properties.html). It's still not working. 

I'm worried all the related questions to this issue are really old, and none of them using the new app.yaml Flexible configuration, so I guess I'm really lost and I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you tried setting the session_affinity parameter to true? This is set up under the network parameter of the app.yaml. [Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/reference/app-yaml#network_settings)